# Add data in Active chart in Excel through VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have a chart which updates every second based on values copied in worksheet from another worksheet.

Every time I have to update the chart with entire range.

Is there a way to edit the chart range to add data points rather than updating the chart with full data?

Comment: Even in VBA, you'll have to redefine the whole range, but if it is a continuous data set, you can get it automatically so it'll be effortless afterwards.

Comment: what do you mean by continuous data set?

Comment: Are you allowed to place the values in a table (ListObject)? If you can, then it is easy to create a dynamic named range which you can use in your chart, and it will automatically include new data points.